# Throughput number formating changes while importing Summary Report to csv file

Tags: jmeter

below 2 images are from Jmeter Summary Report. In the first image, it looks ok but if you double click on the cell, it shows the decimal numbers. When this Summary Report is exported to csv (By clicking on Save Table Data), it does not export it as 8.3/min but exports it as 0.1381...
[image]
[image]

Below is the image from csv file
[image]

Is it a bug? What needs to be done in order to see the number as 8.3/min in csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are always being stored as requests/second, what you see like `/min` or `/hour` is the result of [RateRenderer](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/jorphan/src/main/java/org/apache/jorphan/gui/RateRenderer.java) class transformation which converts requests per second to requests per minute/hour if its below 1

If you want to convert your `0.13812` to "requests per minute" just multiply it by 60.

In general saving listener's report to CSV file is not the best option, you could consider generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) instead and I hope you don't have this and any other Listeners enabled during test execution as [Listeners don't add any value and just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/).